# Hide and show a div based on search input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to hide the `titleMain` div when there is any input in the search field. But for some reason, it isn't working.

I have been trying to show the `titleMain` div when there is no input in the search and hidden when there is any search input.

```js
const searchBar = document.forms['search-books'].querySelector('input');
searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    const term = e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase();
    const books = document.getElementsByTagName('h5');
    var notAvailable = document.getElementById('notAvailable');

    var hasResults = false;
    Array.from(books).forEach(function(book) {
        const title = book.textContent;
        if (title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1) {
            book.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'flex';
            hasResults = true;
        } else {
            book.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
    notAvailable.style.display = hasResults ? 'none' : 'block';
});

if ($('#search').val.length == 0) {
    $("#titleMain").show();
} else {
    $("#titleMain").hide();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" id="titleMain" style="background-color: red;">Book List</div>
<form id="search-books">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Search a book ... ">
</form>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row list-single">
      <div class="col-2"><img src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1447303603s/2767052.jpg"/></div>
      <div class="col-10">
         <h5> The Hunger Games</h5>
         <a href="The-Hunger-Games.html">Learn</a> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="row list-single">
      <div class="col-2"><img src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1507396732s/2.jpg"/></div>
      <div class="col-10">
         <h5>Harry Potter</h5>
         <a href="Harry-Potter.html">Learn</a> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row list-single" id="notAvailable" style="display: none;">
      <div class="col-12">
         <h5>Sorry, the book has not been added yet</h5>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Your `titleMain` div is hidden from the beginning.

Comment: That's the problem. I want the `titleMain` div to be shown when there is no input in the search and hidden when there is search input. @j08691

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the check for your search input in the event handler. You're also not checking the input's value itself. Use `if ($('input').val().length == 0) {`. You can make the show/hide a one liner with `$("#titleMain").toggle($('input').val().length == 0);`:

Example:

```js
const searchBar = document.forms['search-books'].querySelector('input');
searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  const term = e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase();
  const books = document.getElementsByTagName('h5');
  var notAvailable = document.getElementById('notAvailable');
  $("#titleMain").toggle($('input').val().length == 0);
  var hasResults = false;
  Array.from(books).forEach(function(book) {
    const title = book.textContent;
    if (title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1) {
      book.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'flex';
      hasResults = true;
    } else {
      book.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
  notAvailable.style.display = hasResults ? 'none' : 'block';
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" id="titleMain" style="background-color: red;">Book List</div>
<form id="search-books">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search a book ... ">
</form>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row list-single">
    <div class="col-2"><img src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1447303603s/2767052.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <h5> The Hunger Games</h5>
      <a href="The-Hunger-Games.html">Learn</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row list-single">
    <div class="col-2"><img src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1507396732s/2.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <h5>Harry Potter</h5>
      <a href="Harry-Potter.html">Learn</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row list-single" id="notAvailable" style="display: none;">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h5>Sorry, the book has not been added yet</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow! Yes, both the ways are perfect. The single line code is the best choice when I have no other input field on that page. And if I decide to put some other input fields, I may go for more specific but lengthier one. Thank you very much for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move your showing and hiding code into the event listener, so that it runs every time the input changes. <strike>Looks correct apart from that.</strike> `val` is a method which you need to call - `$('#search').val().length`. `$('#search').val.length` will give you the number of arguments expected by `val` - [`Function.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length).